# return the value of a database column from its ID

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I try to return the value of a database column from its ID.
I want to display it in a `<span>` with that ID "#name_page"

I'm sending the ID through POST "`$(this).attr("id")`"

I have my AJAX call

```
$(document).on('click', '.update_btn', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
      url:"fetch_single.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{
        user_id: $(this).attr("id"),
      },
      success:function(data) {  
        $('#name_page').val(data.name_page);
        $('#user_id').val(user_id);            
    }
  });
```

Then I receive it in fetch_single.php

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "test";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name_page FROM table WHERE id = '".$_POST["user_id"]."' 
        LIMIT 1"); 
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

But impossible to get the value back in my webpage

Comment: Using PDO but not `prepare()` with placeholders?

Comment: Looks like you need a `echo json_encode($stmt->fetch());` after your `$stmt->execute();`

Comment: @Sean even if my dataType is not json?

Comment: Using `data.name_page` in `$('#name_page').val(data.name_page);` means you are expecting json

Comment: @sean thanks I'm learning and your comment clarifying my issue. I'm continuing to dig the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not fetching the result, so it will be empty, jquery is also expecting json so you need to json_encode your response.

Also as your using PDO you should be using prepared queries.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "test";

$json = [];

// is POST
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    // check user_id
    if (!isset($_POST["user_id"]) || !is_numeric($_POST["user_id"])) {
        exit(json_encode(['error' => 'Invalid user id']));
    }

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name_page FROM table WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"); 
        $stmt->execute([$_POST["user_id"]]);

        $json = ['name_page' => $stmt->fetchColumn()];
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        $json = ['error' => $e->getMessage()];
    }
    $conn = null;

} else {
    $json = ['error' => 'Sorry expecting POST'];
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

For your jQuery try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.update_btn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var user_id = $(this).attr("id");

    $.ajax({
      url:"fetch_single.php",
      type:"POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data:{
        user_id: user_id,
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#name_page').val(data.name_page);
        $('#user_id').val(user_id);            
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: @lawrence_Cherone Thanks that works well if i simulate a $_POST["user_id"] = "2"; at the top of fetch_single.php but I still have a problem with my AJAX call that doesn't return the fetch_single.php value. Anyway thanks a lot, I have the feeling going foreward =)

Comment: @Odjone see edit, you had a syntax error.. the above should work.

Comment: @lawrence_Cherone works FINE!!! thanks for having helping me... I will read more about dataType:json. Probably my issue was from there. Anyway I really appreciate !!! Have a lovely day/evening